# Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt an arraylist of type EnteredDetails(java bean) and serialise it to a file.I am following this link for AES-128 bit encryption : http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html

To use the method encrypt of aes class I had to convert the arrarylist into byte array which is encrypted using the method encrypt and written it to a file using fileoutputstream.

Now in the deserialize method i used fileinputstream to read that encrypted byte array , decrypted the byte array using decrypt method and than used objectinputstream to get my arraylist back from the decrypted byte array.

This is my Serialize method:

```
    public void serialize() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(ar5.userDetails);
        AES_Encryption en = new AES_Encryption();
        byte[] data=en.encrypt(b.toByteArray());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("user.txt");
        fos.write(data);
        b.close();
        fos.close();
        o.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Edited Deserialize Method :

```
     ArrayList<EnteredDetails> load() {
    try {
        File file=new File("user.txt"); 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("user.txt");
        //            System.out.println("after fisssssss");
       //            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
       //            byte [] d =(byte []) ois.readObject();
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        AES_Encryption enc = new AES_Encryption();
        byte[] data = enc.decrypt(fileContent);
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ObjectInputStream ois2 = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        ArrayList<EnteredDetails> al = (ArrayList<EnteredDetails>) ois2.readObject();
        fis.close();
        b.close();
        ois2.close();
        return al;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception in method load deseialize class " +                    e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error : Given final block not properly padded

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the filters in the reverse order.

You have to decrypt the encrypted data before you can read the object stream.

Comment: I edited the desrialize method but now it is giving error

Given final block not properly padded

Comment: You should close your streams when you are finished with them.

Comment: You are not closing `o` before you attempt to use the data. Hopefully this won't matter.  The key thing is to check that you can decrypt the same data your wrote, and this doesn't appear to be happening.  I would add a check in the writer that you can decrypt the data and deserialize it.

Comment: How to add that check in the writer that you are suggesting? @peter

Comment: When you encrypt the bytes, decrypt them and see that they are the same with Arrays.equals()